# Parsing an xml document in jquery and retrieving HTML data

Tags: jquery, html, xml, parsing, meta-tags

I'm parsing an xml document using jquery successfully, but I can't seem to maintain any of my HTML tags when using: `$(this).find("p").text()`

My xml looks something like this:

```
<block>
  <p><b>Speech:</b> Some text</p>
  <a>http://www.ur.com/</a>
</block>
```

I understand that .text() strips out all html tags, but how do I retrieve the data between my `<p>` tags, so that I end up with `"<b>Speech:</b> Some text"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer, well at least it works for this situation, maybe because my xml tags are reflections of my html content. The problem was in the ajax dataType, I had it set to "xml", and as soon as I set it to "html" I was able to use .html() Method after my .find() Thanks to everyone who contributed.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `.html()` instead of `.text()` which would preserve the html tags

Comment: That was my original throughout but it doesn't work in this case, I get the following error:`TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this[0].innerHTML.replace')`

Comment: Does using .text() return something like "Speech: Some text" or does it give you a similar error?

Comment: I think I found the answer, well at least it works for this situation, maybe because my xml tags are reflections of my html content.

The problem was in the ajax dataType, I had it set to "xml", and as soon as I set it to "html" I was able to use .html() Method after my .find()

Thanks to everyone who contributed.